# How I do refresh apache fom php?

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

i have problem with the refresh of apache from php, in some forums I've seen it recommended the implementation of cron script, but am new to this, someone knows that I can implement to bring this comprehensive and besides the best way for the system task, because I already know the problems get off and upload apache....

any help or opinion will be well received

good night

Comment: You mean restart? Why would you want that?

Comment: what happens is that the restart may work but when the server has a higher load information and click the restart does not start, the solution they recommended me was to do a refresh of apache but my question is whether you can do from php and which is the most appropriate way to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = shell_exec('service apache2 restart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

shell_exec('**shell_command**');

You can execute shell commands by using this function.

**Note:** It will instantly shut down Apache so I don't know what happens in result. You should try to see.

Comment: the problem is that you can go up the server and can not, at first might work but more server load This might cause problems uploading apache